# How to make a row in UITableView invisible?

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new to this field...I'm using a UITableView to create a table in my apps..but based on some certain checks, I need to make some of the rows invisible...how can I achieve that??

Comment: make those checks to return the correct row count every time from `numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: you mean that row should be there but should be blank or the rows should not be there at all.?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you simply have to change the `UITableViewCell` itself. But I don't really know, whether this abides by Apple's HIG (Human Interface Guidelines). Maybe you should consider to remove the cells at all and if you do need them again, add them?